# Passing query parameter value in h:commandLink action

Tags: jsf-2, el

Trying to pass the query parameter value, parameter name targetURL, to the backend bean method via jsf commandLink action.

When I do below (with quote surrounding the param.targetURL) , the literal param.targetURL is being passed to the method:

```
<h:commandLink id="targetURLLink" action="#{commonTaskBean.redirectTo('param.targetURL')}"  style="display:none" />
```

When I do below (without quote surrounding the param.targetURL),

```
<h:commandLink id="targetURLLink" action="#{commonTaskBean.redirectTo(param.targetURL)}"  style="display:none" />
```

I get this error NullPointerException:

```
 9/15/14 9:20:44:529 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R java.lang.NullPointerException
[9/15/14 9:20:44:529 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.paramString(ReflectionUtil.java:315)
[9/15/14 9:20:44:529 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:234)
[9/15/14 9:20:44:529 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:255)
[9/15/14 9:20:44:529 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
[9/15/14 9:20:44:529 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:83)
[9/15/14 9:20:44:530 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:88)
[9/15/14 9:20:44:530 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:100)
[9/15/14 9:20:44:530 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
[9/15/14 9:20:44:530 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:973)
[9/15/14 9:20:44:530 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:275)
[9/15/14 9:20:44:530 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1285)
[9/15/14 9:20:44:530 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:711)
[9/15/14 9:20:44:530 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:34)
[9/15/14 9:20:44:530 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171)
[9/15/14 9:20:44:530 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
[9/15/14 9:20:44:530 CDT] 00000039 SystemErr     R  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
```

I changed the above code to be like below:

```
<h:commandLink id="targetURLLink" actionListener="#{commonTaskBean.redirectTo}" style="display:none" >
    <f:attribute name="targetURL" value="#{param.targetURL}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

But the back-end bean is getting a null value:

```
String targetURL = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("targetURL");
```

Which is weird, because below display the value of targetURL param correctly on the screen:

```
<h:outputText value="#{param.targetURL}"/>
```

Comment: Generally, the full stack trace is helpful in order to see if it's a bug in your own code or in the library. Usually, the full stack trace also represents the whole answer at its own (the key is that we're able to explain it in layman's terms to you). You'd better not omit the stack trace from the question as if it's irrelevant decoration.

Comment: @BalusC:  I updated my post to include relevant stack trace.  For some reason, I'm having a different error today.

Comment: This is a bug in Apache EL. It's already fixed for long in current releases. You're not clear in which container you're using, and the parts hinting about it have unfortunately been omitted from the stack trace, but if it's e.g. Tomcat, then just upgrade it to the latest.

Comment: Thanks Balus.  I'm using websphere 8.0.  It will be required quite a bit of work and coordination to upgrade websphere.  Is there any work around that you know of?

Comment: Depends on whether you want to pass the parameter as available when showing the page with the form, or when submitting the form in the page. The code does actually the latter, but your problem/question suggests the former (not only because it's kind of weird way of grabbing the post data).

Comment: Needed when form is submitted.  I need the redirectTo method to get the actual targetURL value.

Comment: I wasn't asking when you needed it. I was asking when it's available.

Comment: The problem described in your currently latest edit suggests that it's only available when showing the page with the form, not when submitting the form in the page, exactly as I guessed. You need `<f:param>` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is two-fold.

Firstly, the exception you're facing is caused by a bug in a relatively ancient version of Apache EL. It couldn't properly deal with `null`s passed as method arguments. Upgrading the EL implementation (or generally more appropriately, the container implementation), should solve it.

Secondly, you seem to be interested on passing the request parameter which is available when opening the page with the form, not in the request parameter which is available when submitting the form in the page. Referencing `#{param}` as EL method argument approach is then fundamentally wrong. The `#{param}` refers to the request parameter map of the **current** request. At the moment of submitting the form, that's thus the form submit request itself. You need `<f:param>` instead. It's evaluated at the moment when the page with the form is being rendered for the first time (as evidence, you can actually see it in HTML source code).

```
<h:commandLink ... action="#{commonTaskBean.redirectTo}">
    <f:param name="targetURL" value="#{param.targetURL}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

```java
public void redirectTo() throws IOException {
    // ...

    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    String targetURL = ec.getRequestParameterMap().get("targetURL");
    ec.redirect(targetURL);
}
```